# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject on test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have this error when I run my test class, and I can't find how to resolve it, here is the test method :

```
static testMethod void FSControllerTest (){
    Account acc= new Account(Name = 'test');
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp= new Opportunity(Name = 'nomOpp', AccountId = acc.Id, CloseDate = date.newInstance(2017, 02, 02));
    insert opp;

    Contact contact = new Contact(FirstName = 'fisrtName', LastName = 'LastName', AccountId = acc.Id);
    insert contact;

    FSController controller = new FSController (new ApexPages.StandardController(opportunite)); //the error is at this line

}
```

And a sample of the controller to see where the error appens :

```
 public Opportunity opp{get; set;}
 public FSController (ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.opp= (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();

    acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name=:opp.Account.Name LIMIT 1]; //the line where the error appens
 }
```

the Standard controller of my visulaforce page is Opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that the several wrong variable names are just some problems inserted while you were writing your question ("opportunite" instead of "opp").You are requesting the account name instead of its Id.
Here's the solution:

```
acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:opp.AccountId LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry for the errors in variables names (I updated the question) and thank you for your answer !

Comment: I guess you're french because of the variable names :D De rien

Comment: C'est bien de voir des français ici!